# DevExpress HTML after grid view bind

Tags: html, gridview, devexpress

I have a DevExpress grid view on a partial view. After setting all the options and everything I want, I bind the grid view like this:

```
@grid.Bind(Model).GetHtml()
```

This works great, and everything is functional. However, after binding, I tried adding some HTML content at the bottom of the page, but that seems to break some button functionality I have on the main view. I even tried to just add

```
<div>bla</div>
```

and this broke things too. Is this expected behavior? Am I not allowed to add any HTML content after the grid view?

Comment: Why don't you contact DevExpress support directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried adding some HTML content at the bottom of the page, but that seems to break some button functionality

A partial view with a grid should contain only the grid. It can't contain other elements. Remove those HTML tags you have from the grid's PartialView to resolve this problem.

See the *[Why can the alert message with the HTML/JavaScript/CSS content appear when using callback-aware extensions?](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/KA20010)* article for more information.